# FreeCAD CMD color lost after import

Tags: python, freecad

Whenenver I try to import a model via FreeCADCmd Script the objects loose all color information.

This can be checked within the GUI by running macros

```
import FreeCAD
import ImportGui

doc = FreeCAD.newDocument()
FreeCAD.setActiveDocument(doc.Name)
ImportGui.insert("file1.stp", doc.Name)
```

will preserve the colors -- but can not be run on commandline, because of ImportGui.

```
import FreeCAD
import Import

doc = FreeCAD.newDocument()
FreeCAD.setActiveDocument(doc.Name)
Import.insert("file1.stp", doc.Name)
```

will import the model without any color information.

Is there any way to import a step file into FreeCADCmd (commandline -- so no GUI) without the color information being dropped?

Or does anyone know a way to run FreeCAD (GUI Version) without running a xserver?